# openssl_random_pseudo_bytes php function

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

output `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` php function unreadable character.

I use this function to generate a unique string.

```
<?php
header('content-type:text/plain ; charset=utf-8');
$uniqid=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(30 );
echo $uniqid ;
?>
```

output something like this :

```
#~�p�x�6�;g�ic�-z"���:i�
```

Comment: Why would you expect to get a readable string? The documentation does not claim so. It simply produces a string of pseudo random bytes. Not more, not less. No statement about encoding, so you can only use it as 8bit encoding anyway. In short: this function is not meant to offer readable strings.

Comment: Also keep in mind that using a random string _does not guarantee uniqueness_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must use bin2hex() function.

```
<?php
$uniqid=bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(30 ));
echo $uniqid ;
?>
```

also this function certainly does not product a uniqid .

Answer (score 0):

```
private function generateSaltSecretKey($num): string
{
  return  bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($num));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is something like uniqid function in PHP

you can try this:

```
<?php
printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());echo '<br>';
printf("uniqid('php_'): %s\r\n", uniqid('php_'));echo '<br>';
printf("uniqid('', true): %s\r\n", uniqid('', true));echo '<br>';
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php